# Cron script to get current date, match the month number with folder number and zip it

Tags: cron

I'd like a cron that gets the current month (E.G. 02) and matches it against an existing folder (02) and zips the folder recursively.

Currently, I have to update my script to use the new month number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `$(date +\%m)`, which will give you the current month in a two-digit format. From here you can:

```
0 * * * * zip -r backup_$(date +\%m).zip /data/files-$(date +\%m)
```

Which would create a file named `backup_02.zip` containing all the files located in `/data/files-02`. Naturally, do update the file and directory names for your own specific use case.

Hope this helps